# Certification process : Windows Phone -Location Service API

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I upload a windows phone application to the market place ; and the certification process failed ;
The error is

**"Comments: The application does not include a privacy policy explaining how the application uses the location service API.
The application does not appear to use the location service API."**

but the application don't depend on the location service API ! Never !

any one have idea ?

Comment: Perhaps you are adding a location related namespace even if you're not using the api. Try to remove unused "usings" from your project. On Visual Studio Right click on a file -> Organize Usings -> Remove unused usings.

Comment: Contact the market place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of reasons for that type of message:

- Your app references something from one of the Location API namespaces
- A reference used by your app your app references something from one of the Location API namespaces (normally this happens with some Ads frameworks)
- Your WMAppManifest.xml contains the `ID_CAP_LOCATION` capability, thus giving your app Location capabilities.